# Проблема с вызовом функции класса Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        print('1')

class B(A):
    def func2(self):
        print('2')


b = B
A.func = B.func2
b.func() # B.func2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Как я понимаю, мы аргумент self передаем автоматически. Проблема явно не в доступе к функции родителя(аналогичная проблема и с дочерним классом)
Не могу понять что не так

Comment: Для создания объекта нужно добавлять скобки: `b = B()`, тогда `b.func()` будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ты b не делаешь экземпляром класса B, а просто ссылаешься на этот класс. Поэтому, когда ты вызываешь метод func в self ничего не передается, ведь self принимает только экземпляры класса, а сам класс он не подставляет автоматически. Решение проблемы: `b = B()` - тут ты создаешь экземпляр класса.
Чтобы лучше понять проблему, попробуй вызвать метод func через B `B.func()` - вот так. Или так: `A.func()`.
https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit
Этот визуализатор поможет тебе понять, что происходит

Comment: Спасибо большое, я и не заметил... сижу мучаюсь